# Access model in form request when field has same name as entity

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using route model binding in a FormRequest class with unique validation rules

```
class ReasonUpdateRequest extends FormRequest
{


    public function rules()
    {

        return [
            'reason' => 'string|max:255|unique:reasons,reason,' . $this->reason->getKey(),
        ];
    }
}
```

And here's the controller method

```
public function anyReasonUpdate(ReasonUpdateRequest $request, Reason $reason)
{
    //
}
```

I've always been able to access the model that is being bound by doing `$this->entityName`.

The problem is that I can't do `$this->reason->getKey()` to access the id of the reason entity because Reason has a field named `reason`. Now instead of `$this->reason` pointing to the model, it points to the value in that field. I know that a fix could be to rename the field but I'm not in a position to easily do that.

I can get it to work by doing `$reasonId = $this->segment(4);` but this couples it to the format of the url.

How can I access the Reason entity from within my form request object in a more generic way?

Comment: There is something not adding up here.  Why are you using `$this->reason->getKey()` when `Reason` is being passed in via the function.  Can't that just be `$reason->getKey()`?  And why would `$this->reason` return to you the value of the `reason` column?  If you are using dependency injection, that should return to you the instance of `Reason` and work fine.

Comment: @user3158900 I'm using the `$this->entityName->getKey()` approach in plenty of other places and it works fine. In this case `$this->reason` returns the reason column value, rather than the entity like it normally would.

Comment: I think we need to see more code, it's not clear what $this->reason is doing, let's start with where you are trying to call that?

Comment: I have a FormRequest class set up for validation, I'm calling `$this->reason` inside the `rules` method of that class.

Comment: It sounds like somehow, somewhere, someone is setting the properties of your `FormRequest` class to the attributes of the model.  I can't begin to guess how they are doing that exactly but if that's the case, you should be able to grab the `id` of `Reason` by using `$this->id`.  Maybe it's not as good as `getKey()` because it is assuming your database structure but it sounds like your database structure is pretty static anyway.

Comment: I updated with a little more code and clarification. @user3158900 `$this->id`returns `null`. I believe this is just your average route model binding with Form Request validation, nothing special going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get around this by doing:

`$this->route('reason')->getKey()`